# Parse string to find first duplicate character - functional vs. prodecural coding style

Tags: rebol, rebol2, red

I want to parse a string to find the first N duplicate characters found in a `(character, n)` set.

For example, for `"ozzllluu"` and sets ("u" => 2), ("d" => 2), ("l" => 3), and ("r" => 3)... I would want to find "lll", because it is 3 characters and happens before the two "u"s.

procedural style solution:

```
Rebol []

seq-set: [#"u" 2 #"d" 2 #"l" 3 #"r" 3]
str: "ozzllluu"

lastchar: ""
cnt: 1
seq-char: ""

foreach char str [
    either char = lastchar [ 
        cnt: cnt + 1
        if (select seq-set char) = cnt [
            seq-char: char
            break
         ]
   ][
        cnt: 1
   ]
   lastchar: char   
]

either seq-char = "" [
    print "no seq-char"
][
    print join "seq-char " seq-char
]
```

How would I do this same thing using a `parse` rule?

In short:

- `parse` string for first n duplicate character found in (character ,n) set
- "function" the existing procedural code
- dogfood into Rebol / Red!

Comment: Hint: be really careful about "humor" in questions or answers. Your approach simply confused me. You want that other people spend their time to help you. There is no need to be funny for that; neither when asking; nor when answering. Yes, sometimes that is just nice, but especially in "written only" conversations, "good humor" is **hard**.

Comment: @GhostCat
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food -
   search "Microsoft"

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution using Red's Parse (works in R3 too):

```
seq-set: [2 #"u" | 2 #"d" | 3 #"l" | 3 #"r"]
rule: [any [set char seq-set break | skip]]

red>> parse "ozzllluu" rule
red>> char
== #"l"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple rule  as a starting point

```
keys:  ["uu" | "dd" | "lll" | "rrr"]
rule: [(k: none)  any [[copy k keys to end ] | skip] ]

>> parse "olllddsslll rr rrr" rule  k
== "lll"
```

Comment: Easy enough to build that rule too: **`remove collect [foreach [ch rp]["u" 2 "d" 2 "l" 3 "r" 3][keep '| keep head insert/dup copy ch ch rp - 1]]`**

Answer (score 1):

Below `parse` rule finds all duplicates and skips the others.

```
;Rebol 2 version
char: charset [#"a" - #"z"]
parse/all "wqooossssccfgg" [some [
    copy x char [copy y some x (print [s: join x y length? s])]
    | skip 
  ]
]
;output
ooo 3
ssss 4
cc 2
gg 2

;Red version
parse "wqooossssccfgg" [some [
    copy x char [copy y some x (print [s: append x y length? s])]
| skip ]]
```